# Action bar disappearing after adding ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have written an xml code and after that I found that the contents exceeds the screen size so I tried adding an ScrollView but after adding that the Action bar disappears

Here is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">





    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Whipped Cream"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chocolate_checkbox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chocolate"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="decrement"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="increment"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="order summary"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$10"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="order"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"/>



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I also tried putting the ScrollView inside the LinearLayout but that way it gave an error

> Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child

What I am doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: Have you executed the code and checked on device or emulator? I think you are looking in the design view of Android Studio.

Comment: @MonishKamble Yeah! you are right. I works perfectly as it should in my device but why it is not showing in the preview pane in Android Studio?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason behind it. But I guess as it is a Layout Editor it should show the complete elements which are there in the layout.  And  in case of `ScrollView` the height is not limited and there is no scroll feature in the design view. Thus, while showing a preview of `ScrollView` it shows only the content, removing the action bar, status bar and the device frame.

Answer (score -1):

**I am making a correction based on your code -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:fitWindowSystem="true" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Whipped Cream"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chocolate_checkbox"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chocolate"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="quantity"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:onClick="decrement"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:onClick="increment"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="order summary"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$10"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="order"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"/>



        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know how it goes.